# passing typedef function pointers as parameter doesn't work in Arduino 1.6.5

Tags: arduino, function-pointers, typedef

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a bit. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or passing typedef function pointers as parameter doesn't work in Arduino 1.6.5?

I have this:

```
typedef int (*arithmeticOperation)(int a, int b);
```

and this:

```
int multiply(int a, int b){
  return a*b;
}
```

This works:

```
arithmeticOperation result; 
result = multiply; 
Serial.println(result(5, 2));
```

And if I have a function like this:

```
void printResult(int x, int y, int (*arithmeticOperation)(int, int)){
  Serial.println(arithmeticOperation(x, y));
}
```

This works as well

```
printResult(5, 3, multiply);
printResult(5, 4, result);
```

But having a function like this:

```
void test(int x, int y, arithmeticOperation result){
  Serial.println(result(x, y));
}
```

To be called like this:

```
test(5, 4, multiply);
test(5, 4, result);
```

Doesn't work on Arduino 1.6.5. Why?

EDIT:

**It doesn't work on the Arduino IDE 1.6.5 on a Mid-2014  MacBook Pro  OSX 10.10.5 The compiler version it uses is avr-g++(GCC) 4.8.1**

[Here are some codes in gist](https://gist.github.com/mithi/b46d56850552a5df7a97).

Here's [File3.ino](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mithi/b46d56850552a5df7a97/raw/e0ac5e7759ea93c93027c3df0a9d69ef84042976/File3.ino) which produces this error in Arduino IDE 1.6.5:

```
File3.ino:4:25: error: 'arithmeticOperation' has not been declared 'arithmeticOperation' has not been declared
```

## Answer: It doesn't work on Arduino IDE 1.6.5, but it works on Arduino IDE 1.6.6 on OSX 10.10.5

Comment: Do you get a compile-time error or a run-time one?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Clang compiles this code just fine (though I'm on x64 not Arduino).

Comment: Perhaps you should try to examine the error message and extract some useful information from it.

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? Please choose at most one of the two.

Comment: Whether you are using "C" or "C++" (there is no "C/C++" language recognized here) depends on whether your build invokes "avr-gcc" or "avr-g++".

Comment: Please post *complete sources that produce the error* (not sources with bad constructs commented out and/or omitted headers) and *full unedited error messages*. This means, copy and paste them from the beginning to the end, without omitting anything in the middle. Like, I dunno, line numbers. Post **directly in the question** (no links to outside resources).

Comment: Please uncomment your erroneous lines, add any missing headers, and post the code *directly in the question* (no outside links).

Comment: @MiniMithi: I compiled your code successfully on Mac OS using avr-gcc and avr-g++ 4.9.1 from MacPorts.  What version of avr-g++ are you using?  Can you try it on the command line?  I commented out the Serial calls to simplify.

Comment: @JohnZwinck its avr-g++ 4.8.1 I'll install the latest stable version Arduino IDE 1.6.6 (still downloading) and see if it uses the same version you compiled it with. If not i'll go figure out if I can make my Arduino IDE use that version instead. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnZwinck it works on Arduino IDE 1.6.6, it didn't work on Arduino IDE 1.6.5 thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It doesn't work on Arduino IDE 1.6.5 but it works on Arduino IDE 1.6.6 on OSX 10.10.5 both use avr-g++ (GCC) 4.8.1

Comment: Using Arduino 1.8.13 on an up to date Fedora Linux here, and it does not work. The workaround in your question works well though.Thanks!